# What should I use as a buffer in C++ for receiving data from network sockets?

Tags: c++, sockets, raw-sockets, buffer

I'm using sockets with C++. The program simply requests an HTTP page, reads it into a buffer `buf[512]`, and then displays the buffer. However pages can contain more data than the buffer, so it will cut off if there is no more space left. I can make the buffer size bigger, but that doesn't seem like a good solution. This is the code that I am using:

```
char buf[512];
int byte_count = recv(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
```

What would be an alternative to a char array in C++ to use as a buffer?

Comment: Since this is an HTTP request the page size may be contained in the header information. If you can retrieve that you can dynamically allocate memory (use std::vector<char>) to hold the whole page. Note just because web server sent 200 bytes does not mean you will recieve them in one block. The transport is allowed to break it up into smaller blocks and you should loop until recv() returns 0 or an error code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you intend to do with the data. If you just want to dump it to an output stream, then the proper thing to do is to do what you're doing, but do it in a loop until there's no more data to read, writing the buffer to the output stream after each read.

Answer (score 1):

There basically isn't one - when using recv, you need to call it repeatedly until it has read all your input. You can of course use more advanced sockets libraries that support growing buffers, but for plain old recv(), a n array of char (or vector of char) is what you need.

You can of course append the data you read into a dynamic buffer such as a string:

```
string page;
while( len = recv( ... ) ) {
   page.append( buf, len );
}
```